# Call constructor within class definition

Tags: python, ruby, constructor

I have this code in Ruby that I wanted to translate to Python.

```
class PortableType
     private
     def initialize(name, long_name)
          @name = name
          @long_name = long_name
     end

     public
     Int8 = PortableType.new(:int8, "Integer8")
     Int16 = PortableType.new(:int16, "Integer16")

     TYPES = [Int8, Int16]
end
```

I wrote this:

```
class PortableType:
     def __init__(self, name, long_name):
          self.name = name
          self.long_name = long_name

     global_TYPES = [PortableType("int8", "Integer8"), PortableType("int16", "Integer16")]
```

But it doesn't work, `PortableType` is an "**undefined variable**". It appears that I can't call the class constructor within the same class. Is there a way to do what I want in Python?

Comment: You can't call the class while you're still in the middle of defining it. You can do that and assign to a class property *after* the class has been defined. In fact, I'd suggest you make those *types* a *module* property instead of a class property, that would seem to make more sense to me. A class having instances of itself as properties is a bit weird.

Comment: You do realise that unlike python, ruby is not white-space sensitive, right? You must finish each method definition/class definition explicitly with `end`. Indentation is irrelevant. So, your "ruby code" isn't valid. Also, have a look through one of the many ruby [style guides](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby/coding-style) for pointers; the ruby community is pretty consistent in how code is written.

Comment: You can just do it afterwards: `PortableType.TYPES = [...]`, Python doesn't stop you adding new attributes. But it's not a very idiomatic approach.

Comment: @Tom Lord I just forgot the end, I edited my post. I am aware that ruby is not white-space sensitive.

Comment: By the way, within a class definition body, `self` is the class, and since `self` is the implicit receiver, you can just say `Int8 = new(:int8, 'Integer8')`. Also, `initialize` is `private` by default, and everything else is `public` by default, so you can just get rid of the calls to `public` and `private`. Lastly, indentation in Ruby is 2 spaces, not 5. That has nothing to do with your question, of course, but it will make your Ruby code much more idiomatic.